# What's the difference between "Stuck Thread Max Time" and "Max Stuck Thread Time" in Weblogic 10.3.x?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, workmanagers

Weblogic 10.3.6 Admin Console has two parameters related with Stuck Threads time configuration.

One in: `Servers -> Some_Server -> Configuration -> Tuning` has the parameter: `Stuck Thread Max Time`

Other in: `Servers -> Some_Server -> Configuration -> Overload` has the parameter: `Max Stuck Thread Time`

In some tests that I did, only the parameter in `Overload` configuration seems to trigger the `Failure Action` in same tab configuration. I can't figure out what  the parameter in `Tuning` tab does.
In the Oracle oficial documentation both parameters has the same description but are related with different MBeans:

[Stuck Thread Max Time] ServerMBean.StuckThreadMaxTime (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/Corecoreserverserverconfigtuningtitle.html)

[Max Stuck Thread Time] ServerFailureTriggerMBean.MaxStuckThreadTime (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/pagehelp/Corecoreserverserverconfigoverloadtitle.html)

My question is, what's the difference between these parameters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Tuning** = stuck thread reporting

```
Servers -> Some_Server -> Configuration -> Tuning -> Stuck Thread Max Time
```

This will check on the Stuck Thread Timer Interval for any and all stuck threads and report it in the log file for the server like: `'WebLogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "zzz" seconds working on the request "------" , which is more than the configured time (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds.`

**Overload** =  stuck thread reaction

```
Servers -> Some_Server -> Configuration -> Overload -> Max Stuck Thread Time
```

Max Stuck Thread Time specifies the length of time after which the server considers a thread stuck. If a total of Stuck Thread Count threads become stuck, the server transitions itself to a failed state. Once the server transitions to a failed state. Failure Action on the overload tab controls what action to take to correct the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And it's make no sense that weblogic has this independent parameters for the same thing, bizarre! :)

Comment: Agreed - these settings are not well documented. Answer comes from experience + weblogic books/articles

Comment: i set "Max Stuck Thread Time" to 10 and "Stuck Thread Count" to 5, during stress test with 100 concurrent requests each run for 100 seconds, the server should become failed state right? but my server keep in warning state regardless the number of concurrent threads running. I am using WL version 10.3.6.0 and java version 1.7.0_80. Is there other configurations needed?

Comment: the server will become failed only if you have set "Panic Action:" different to "Ignore, take no action", and "Stuck Thread Count:" is greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Weblogic-12.2.1.4.0

---

### In 'Tuning', ---- Stuck Thread Max Time

As it named, the value provided here will be the 'Max Time' (Maximum Time), after which 'Thread' will be considered as 'Stuck'.
This parameter is imposed on each and every SINGLE thread and not on group of threads.

e.g.

- Suppose, Stuck Thread Max Time = 600 seconds
  Then, if a thread exceeds 600 seconds to complete then it will be considered as stuck thread.

---

### In 'Overload' ---- Max Stuck Thread Time

Here it is bit tricky, If 'Maximum number of Stuck Threads' stays as it is for more that given time then server will be considered as failed.
This parameter is imposed on GROUP of threads and not on SINGLE thread.

e.g.
Suppose Parameter Values were as follows.

- Max Stuck Thread Time: 600 seconds
- Stuck Thread Count: 10

Then based on above parameter,
If 10 stuck threads are in queue for more that 600 seconds, then server will be transitioned into FAILED state.